# Xcode6 swift type inference bug?

Tags: ios, swift

Any view controller by adding the following code:

The Xcode6 will stop working.

Unable to compile and run.

is a xcode problem?

```
let popularTableData = [
    [
        "id": 1,
        "title": "xxx"
    ],
    [
        "id": 2,
        "title": "xxx"
    ],
    [
        "id": 3,
        "title": "xxx"
    ],
    [
        "id": 4,
        "title": "xxx"
    ],
    [
        "id": 5,
        "title": "xxx"
    ],
    [
        "id": 6,
        "title": "xxx"
    ],
    [
        "id": 7,
        "title": "xxx"
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a bug.  The Swift compiler has a problem determining the type of `popularTableData` in this case.  Give it some help by explicitly declaring the type:

```
let popularTableData: [[String: AnyObject]] = [
```

I placed your code in a Playground, and it eventually worked (after over a minute).  The compile time seems to increase exponentially with each extra dictionary element added to the array.  When you tell the compiler the type, it compiles quickly.